# Got a Yamaha MBK 100cc scooter the problem

Tags: starting, yamaha, scooter

Yamaha MBK 100cc starting problem turn the key no lights on the dash no electric start but it will start off kick start but still no light none ov them

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Have you checked the condition of the battery to make sure it has a charge? No lights/start ... this is the first place I'd look.

Answer (score 1):

Don't have enough points to comment, but I agree with Paulster2.  Almost certainly you have a marginal battery.  Enough power for the relatively low demands of the electronic ignition while you kick start, not enough to power the electric starter or instruments.